# how to build a iphone front to connect a php/mysql server and do some search?

Tags: iphone, database

This is my interview question. My potential boss told me to do it in one week and tomorrow is the last day. I am a green hand in iphone development. I searched and tried a lot but still get nothing. I set up an mySQL database but failed to write the php pages. Is it necessary to write a php page? or I can do the task without the php? Please give me a hand. I just want to implement a simple search, pull data from the backend and display on the iphone.

Comment: Perhaps this is a good indication you aren't qualified for the job? Why would you want a job in something you have no experience in doing? Sounds like you'd just be setting yourself up for failure.

Comment: Time to start sending out new resumes, and apply for jobs you're better suited to.

Comment: oh, you guys told me to give up. But that is not I am going to do.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you give up or not. You can't learn iOS development and build an iOS app as well as a PHP web service in 24 hours. Even if you wind up with the job, you'll quickly find yourself in over your head.

Comment: We're not going to help you lie to your potential boss (think about it, it will get you and your new boss in trouble).

I did provide you with a little info on how this is supposed to work though.
If you cannot figure that out, you are applying for the wrong job.

Comment: why u people think I lie? My new boss knows about me. He wanted me to learn. he knows i can't do right now and he wished I could try.

Answer (score 4):

If your boss wants to promote you / change your responsibilites you shouldn't be trying to fake it, you should be asking for training :)

And if it's for a new job then I don't think faking that is a good idea at all!

Comment: It's a new job but I'm not faking. My potential boss knows I have no experience in this field. Why? Is that so unbelievable?

Comment: No, it's not unbelievable but you should mention that in the question ;) To answer this question you need to know about a few different fields, iOS, PHP, possibly database stuff and maybe API design. I'd go back to your boss saying without training / a mentor this is an impossible task in the timeframe!

Comment: If he knows you have no experience in the field, why on earth would he give you such a large starting project?

Comment: Is it a large project? Oh, God help me! Maybe it is too hard to hire enough people now. I remembered he told to me: we need some of your advantage but you can not know nothing. So he give me one week.

Comment: Yes, this is a pretty big project, particularly for someone who's asking basic questions like this. If you've had a week and you're only now asking these questions, you're screwed.

Comment: Yes. I will show him the other things I did during the last week. After that I will give myself a happy weekend and next monday I will apply for other jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of hints :

1) your iPhone has no access to the database on the server.

2 ) you need to write some kind of gateway in PHP that will fetch the information from the database

3 ) your php code should transmit it to the iPhone in a parseable format

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I should continue to study php, setting up the server

Comment: Here's another tip : if you have no idea of php, and how this works, don't apply for any jobs that require it. you will not get them.

Comment: I got it but still I won't give up.

Comment: seems like you guys are genius before you born. Anyway thank you

Comment: Nope, none of us were (neither was Bill Gates, or Edsger Dijkstra, or *insert famous programmer here* ). we spent a lot of time learning, each and every one of us.

Comment: I am learning now but I got only arrogance and denial in here. Can't believe that!

Comment: But I still get answer. I asked "is it necessary to write a php page?" and you said yes. :)

Comment: BTW, about the "genius" thing, as you said you think I was praising you? Ohh....

Comment: I'm getting an "ill reception v/s ill response vibe" here. if you're going to ask questions on Stack Overflow, stick to the short, technical portion of a problem.
Telling us it's for your boss is none of our info and might even (as you noticed) have ill effect.
If you especially take the time to berate the only people helpful to you, and patient enough to provide any help at all, good luck with that.

Comment: I apologize and thank you at all. Also, I have solved the problem and build the demo project. Wish everyone good luck!